# how can i correctly insert arguments and integers to my function in python?

Tags: python

I've got a two part question that involves around functions of python..

a) Write a function speak_excitedly that accepts a required argument (a message) and two optional arguments, the first of which is a positive integer that refers to the number of exclamation marks to be set at the end of the message (default is 1). The second optional argument is a Boolean, which indicates whether the message should be capitalized or not (default is False, i.e. it should not be capitalized).

b) How would you call this function to generate the following output? I love Python! Optional arguments are great!!!!! Java is so mediocre... LET'S GO TIGERS!!

What I've tried: well i know that for function that you should begin with **def speak_excitedly ()** but i don't know how to correctly insert arguments and integers to my function

Comment: The internet is filled with Python tutorials and other information that would help with this question, including [the python documentation itself](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 0):

There is so many way to make this, like

> a

```
def speak_excitedly(message, ex_mark=1, cap=True):
    txt = message + '!'*ex_mark
    if cap:
        txt = txt.upper()
    return txt
```

> b

```
message = r"I love Python! Optional arguments are great!!!!! Java is so mediocre... LET'S GO TIGERS!!"
print(speak_excitedly(message, 2))
```

Beware, dont forget to use `r' '` instead of a plain `' '` as there are several `'`. Or use `" "` instead.

Comment: That `message = ` line raises a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
def speak_excitedly(message, marks = 1, case = False):
   res = message + '!' * marks
   if case:
      res = res.upper()
   return res
```

To call the function,

```
lis = ["I love Python", " Optional arguments are great", " Java is so mediocre...", " Let's go tigers"]
final_ans = ""
final_ans += speak_excitedly(lis[0])
final_ans += speak_excitedly(lis[1], 5)
final_ans += speak_excitedly(lis[2], 0)
final_ans += speak_excitedly(lis[3], 2, True)
print(final_ans)
```